# User defined function based on multiple columns grouped by category

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

This may be basic, but I've been trying to figure it out for days and haven't found an answer.

I am trying to calculate a new quantity based on two columns 'concentration' and 'area' grouped by 'catchment'. I've written a function to calculate the difference in concentration for each row and the row with the largest area normalized by proportion of area in that catchment, but it won't work with `dplyr` or `aggregate` (. It works fine with by, but then returns a list.

Ideally, I want to add a column onto the dataframe or replace the concentration column altogether. Here is the dataframe 'lev':

```
  area catchment concentration
1    1       Yup       2.00000
2   10       Yup      40.50000
3   25       Yup      50.82031
4   35       Yup      50.00000
5    1      Nope       1.00000
6   10      Nope       5.00000
7   25      Nope      40.08333
8   35      Nope      38.00000
```

Here is the function:

```
lever <- function(data=lev, x=data[,"concentration"], y=data[,"area"]){
N= which.max(y) 
L = (x - x[N]) * y/max(y)
return(L)}
```

And here is the desired result:

```
   area catchment concentration   leverage
1    1       Yup       2.00000 -1.3714286
2   10       Yup      40.50000 -2.7142857
3   25       Yup      50.82031  0.5859375
4   35       Yup      50.00000  0.0000000
5    1      Nope       1.00000 -1.0571429
6   10      Nope       5.00000 -9.4285714
7   25      Nope      40.08333  1.4880952
8   35      Nope      38.00000  0.0000000
```

Using `by`, I can get two lists with the results for each catchment:

```
by(lev, lev$catchment, lever)
```

but I want to use the function on multiple columns categorized by several factors (e.g. date in addition to catchment) and I get

> 'incorrect number of dimensions'

errors with `doBy` and `dplyr`.

Comment: We can give better answers if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451).

Comment: Thanks for editing it to make it reproducible. I'll do better next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading your data:

```
lev <- read.table(text = "area catchment concentration
    1       Yup       2.00000
   10       Yup      40.50000
   25       Yup      50.82031
   35       Yup      50.00000
    1      Nope       1.00000
   10      Nope       5.00000
   25      Nope      40.08333
   35      Nope      38.00000", 
   header=TRUE)
```

Grouped by catchment

```
library(dplyr)
lev %>% 
    group_by(catchment) %>% 
    mutate(N = which.max(area),
           L = (concentration - concentration[N]) * area/max(area))

# 
#    area catchment concentration     N          L
#   <int>    <fctr>         <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
# 1     1       Yup       2.00000     4 -1.3714286
# 2    10       Yup      40.50000     4 -2.7142857
# 3    25       Yup      50.82031     4  0.5859357
# 4    35       Yup      50.00000     4  0.0000000
# 5     1      Nope       1.00000     4 -1.0571429
# 6    10      Nope       5.00000     4 -9.4285714
# 7    25      Nope      40.08333     4  1.4880929
# 8    35      Nope      38.00000     4  0.0000000
```

## Using your function

I modify your function so that it returns a data frame.

```
lever2 <- function(data, 
                   x = data[,"concentration"][[1]], 
                   y = data[,"area"][[1]]){
    # Use [[1]] to extract the vector only
    N <- which.max(y)
    L <- (x - x[N]) * y/max(y)
    # Put L back into the data frame 
    # so that we keep the concentration and area in the result
    data$L <- L
    return(data)
    }
```

The funtion can then be used with `dplyr::group_by %>% do`

```
lev %>% 
    group_by(catchment) %>% 
    do( lever2(.))
```

Comment: Yes I was writing at the same time on my laptop, but I'm slower than you. I though about adding an example using the OP's function `lever` and the `group_by` %>% `do` mechanism, but somehow this returns `(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` I still have to figure out how to make this one work.

Comment: Works perfect! If I have multiple columns (e.g. concentration1, concentration2), how could I add the L to the dataframe for each one?

Comment: Edit the `mutate` instruction `L = (concentration2 - concentration2[N]) * area/max(area)`. But if you have a wide data structure, you might consider reshaping the data frame to a long format with [tidyr::gather](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) before performing the `mutate`.

Comment: @benjabiker I added an example using a modified version of your function.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(catchment) %>%
  mutate(leverage = (concentration- concentration[which.max(area)]) * area/max(area))
```

---

Based on the description, if there are multiple columns as grouping variable, place those in the `group_by`, and the calculation can also be applied to multiple columns with `mutate_each`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table` to calculate this value:

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table
setDT(df)

df[, leverage := (concentration - concentration[which.max(area)]) * (area / max(area)),
   by=catchment]
df
   area catchment concentration   leverage
1:    1       Yup       2.00000 -1.3714286
2:   10       Yup      40.50000 -2.7142857
3:   25       Yup      50.82031  0.5859357
4:   35       Yup      50.00000  0.0000000
5:    1      Nope       1.00000 -1.0571429
6:   10      Nope       5.00000 -9.4285714
7:   25      Nope      40.08333  1.4880929
8:   35      Nope      38.00000  0.0000000
```

**data**

```
df <-
structure(list(area = c(1L, 10L, 25L, 35L, 1L, 10L, 25L, 35L), 
    catchment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Nope", 
    "Yup"), class = "factor"), concentration = c(2, 40.5, 50.82031, 
    50, 1, 5, 40.08333, 38)), .Names = c("area", "catchment", 
"concentration"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```